# How to interpret the ML Monitor various DB size figures against the physical windows diskspace figures

Tags: optimization, marklogic, database-administration

I am trying to understand the relationship between conventional windows disk size against those different disk size figures from ML Monitor screen.
That might be important to understand the [ML Minimum Disk Space Requirements](https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/284/0/understanding-marklogic-minimum-disk-space-requirements).

**Question**

<1> From those below screenshots, I want to know how to know the **detail calculation steps** on whether host 1 meets the ML Minimum Disk Space Requirements.

<2> Is there an ML Admin API to query those disk size programmably? (I need to set up an alert if the diskspace is below a matrices.)

Below 3 screenshots are from the same Host 1 machine. (Let us use that as the example to work out the calculation matrices.)

[image: ML Monitoring Screen for Host 1 Data Folder]

1. Fast Data: ?
2. Large Data: 38.24 G
3. Forest Data: 99.47 G
4. Forest Reserve: 65.54 G
5. Free: 135.13 G

[image: Host 1 Data Folder Size]
Windows Disk Size D:\Data:  136 G.
D: drive fee disk size: 195 G

[image]